# Octahedral impostors, Octahedral mapping

Tags: opengl, mathematics, rendering, billboarding

I'm facing some issues understanding [this article about octahedral impostors](https://shaderbits.com/blog/octahedral-impostors).

More specifically I quite don't understand how one can map the hemi-octahedron (subdivided) vertices to texture coordinates.

Quote from the article :

> "For those not familiar with octahedra, they are a convenient way to convert between 2D and 3D space, or vice versa."

This two images help visualize the transformation:

[image: Animated example of transformation]

Here we can see an animated transition from a tesselated quad mesh to a hemisphere or a full sphere.

[image: Imposter layout showing a view associated with each vertex]

Here we see a view of the model to be imitated associated with each vertex of the mesh, giving coverage of viewpoints around the hemisphere: side views around the perimeter of the square, and top-down views near the center.

I don't understand the math used to perform this mapping from the square domain of the quad to the hemisphere or sphere of directions around the model.

[This article also says that we can easily map 3D to 2D uvs](https://lightbulbbox.wordpress.com/2018/05/01/improved-impostor-rendering/), without explaining how or why. I found a few research papers about octahedron and normals compression but it is quite a different problem and honestly I didn't really get the grasp of them.

**Could someone explain to me how to map a vertex expressed in 3D (ie impostor camera position) from the octahedron to a plain 2D texture?**

The goal is to be able to cast a ray to the octahedron and map the hit point coordinates to 2D uvs, or find the nearest vertex and render the texture associated with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start by going from the [0,1]x[0,1] UV domain to a complete unit octahedron, running from -1 to 1 on each axis:

```
float3 UVtoOctahedron(float2 uv) {
    // Unpack the 0...1 range to the -1...1 unit square.
    float3 position = float3(2.0f * (uv - 0.5f), 0);                

    // "Lift" the middle of the square to +1 z, and let it fall off linearly
    // to z = 0 along the Manhattan metric diamond (absolute.x + absolute.y == 1),
    // and to z = -1 at the corners where position.x and .y are both = +-1.
    float2 absolute = abs(position.xy);
    position.z = 1.0f - absolute.x - absolute.y;

    // "Tuck in" the corners by reflecting the xy position along the line y = 1 - x
    // (in quadrant 1), and its mirrored image in the other quadrants.
    if(position.z < 0) {
        position.xy = sign(position.xy) 
                    * float2(1.0f - absolute.y, 1.0f - absolute.x);
    }

    return position;
}
```

We can of course normalize the position to "puff it out" to a unit sphere.

Now that we have the full unit octahedron, it's simple to get just the top pyramid: we just map our UV quad to just the inner diamond \$|x| + |y| \leq 1\$, then do the same lift as before:

[image: Diagram showing the mapping from uv to position xy]

Here the origin of our UV space sits at the bottom of the unit diamond (0, -1). Moving a distance of 1 along the U direction brings us up & right (+1, +1) to arrive at the right corner. And moving a distance of 1 along the V direction takes us up & left (-1, +1). I fold the addition of the origin, U, and V components into the calculation of `position` below:

```
float3 UVtoPyramid(float2 uv) {
    float3 position = float3(
                         0.0f + (uv.x - uv.y),
                        -1.0f + (uv.x + uv.y),
                         0.0f
                    );

    float2 absolute = abs(position.xy);
    position.z = 1.0f - absolute.x - absolute.y;    
    // No need for the final "tuck in" fold since we're skipping the bottom half.

    return position;
}
```

And again, this can be normalized to "puff out" to a rounded hemisphere.

Now, mapping from a 3D direction to 2D is just a matter of inverting the operation. Let's say we have a (unit) vector pointing out from our imposter position toward the viewer. To place that in UV space we can...

```
float2 OctahedronUV(float3 direction) {
    float3 octant = sign(direction);

    // Scale the vector so |x| + |y| + |z| = 1 (surface of octahedron).
    float sum = dot(direction, octant);        
    float3 octahedron = direction / sum;    

    // "Untuck" the corners using the same reflection across the diagonal as before.
    // (A reflection is its own inverse transformation).
    if(octahedron.z < 0) {
        float3 absolute = abs(octahedron);
        octahedron.xy = octant.xy
                      * float2(1.0f - absolute.y, 1.0f - absolute.x);
    }

    return octahedron.xy * 0.5f + 0.5f;
}
```

And again, chopping down to just the top pyramid if we have only a hemisphere to work with...

```
float2 PyramidUV(float3 direction) {
    float3 octant = sign(direction);

    float sum = dot(direction, octant);
    float3 octahedron = direction / sum;    

    return 0.5f * float2(
              1.0f + octahedron.x + octahedron.y,
              1.0f + octahedron.y - octahedron.x
           );
}
```

Here our last step is to transform our xy space so its inner unit diamond maps to the [0,1]x[0,1] UV square, and the unused triangles hang off the edges, like so:

[image: Diagram of mapping from xy position back to UV]

Here the xy origin maps to the center of the UV space (0.5, 0.5), and moving a distance of 1 along either the x or y moves us 0.5 along each of U & V.

Now that you have your point in UV space, you can round it to your desired increments to snap to the closest grid intersection.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it is very clear and well detailed. There is only one part I quite don't get yet. When you map the unit quad (UV) to the inner diamond ```|x| + |y| <= 1```. I don't quite understand the operations you use when you set the ```float3 position```. They are probably related to the equation but can't figure it out. The rest is crystal clear, could you just detail a bit more on that ?